# Error - Android app causes UNKNOWN kind of performance degradation (weird Samsung issue)

Tags: android, performance, debugging, galaxy

Testing on Samsung Galaxy Note Edge, Android 6.0.1

PLEASE NOTE - this issue happens only on Samsung Phones with pre-installed "Smart Manager". If you have no experience with that constellation, please read in detail whats the real issue. This is irregular, not a usual debugging thing. Please don't expect a code snippet right now, there cant be one. At this point I cant post any reasonable line of code because the origin of those errors is COMPLETELY UNCLEAR. I have only 4500 lines, and 25 classes, but absolutely no clue where to pick a meaningful snippet from without any hint what Smart Manager complains concretely. It says just one word: "ERROR", but not when, not why, not what ... Mission Impossible

I've researched a lot now, but found almost nothing being of help. My app is compiling fine without errors and running smoothly (and very fast!) as desired. I cant feel anything about "performance degradation", but Samsung "Smart Manager" has this very weird issue with my app...

[image: Smart Manager 1]

[image]

Battery lasts for days on standby, no heat, nothing notably.

No information what kind of error should have been occurred at all. No more details to open, simply nothing!

My app does definitely not run in background. It stops, pauses and resumes without issues. No issues, no errors during building (Android Studio 2.2), no warnings about Smart Manager performance  issues, this error pops up ONE WEEK LATER, or two or three. That's why I you have no chance to create a link between error and possible root cause to start tracking down. In that time you made lots of code changes before you get notified from SM the first time, lots of Git commits, but which one contains the change this external tool complains? That makes it a real hell.

I also let it connected for 5 days to USB, collecting tons of logs, crawling the logcat like crazy for any relevant events, but SAMSUNG's Smart Manager doesn't seem any need to log at least one word when it counts its ominous errors.

What I've found on the net, nobody really knows how to debug this, just very time-consuming guesses which I followed where applicable - without success.

What I've already tried:

- Exceptions - all caught and handled
- Removed all debug logging output
- Checked for infinite loops
- Checked for missing or damaged resource files
- Disabled auto-translation
- Checked for whatever could be irregular, suspicious or extraterrestrial

And after making changes I must wait days or weeks if it will finally pop up again or not...

Could there be any way to catch those Smart Manager error count events and attach some whatever sort of logging to it? There is no documentation from Samsung anywhere, no support for this pre-installed app, no help at all.

Comment: It is even more UNKNOWN without code...

Comment: Your app was crashing,  sort that out and you should be fine.

Comment: I should really post all my code? Bit to much! Where to start, for what to look for???

Comment: This turns into a rant towards the end. We don't like rants here; we like programming questions, Please [edit] your question to (a) remove the bit where you get pissed off at a company that isn't even going to read this, (b) add a [mcve] so we can see the minimal code that causes this to happen, and (c) tone down the emoji; they're never necessary, and they make this look like a Facebook post, not like part of something that's supposed to be an archive of high-quality programming questions. One or two would be fine, but this many is too much.

Comment: I've edited it. Sry, but sometimes... The issue is, nobody really understands what is happening here. Of course, I would love to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable example - I already understood this clearly and this is not new to me. But please understand, there is no link between those smart manager errors (popping up days later) and any nameable place in my code where to start. For what to look for? I cant give an example because those errors dont tell you anything anout the reason behind. No detail ecplanation. SM says just "errors"...

Comment: 25 classes, 4500 lines of code, and not even a tiny hint where it could maybe originate from. This is not an usual issue and has absolutely nothing to do with logcat. There are no logs and no traces. The issue could persist since weeks because Smart Manager runs in background and nobody knows when it has collected enough "errors" to pop up finally. Other users have 47 errors or even more.

Comment: Btw. I monitored RAM and CPU two weeks ago, there is nothing wrong. SAM Battery Monitor says the app used 1,7% since last charge. Battery cant be the issue. My app doesnt calculate anything or running excessive concurrent threads. Don't know what to say much more. Hope it will read someone having also a Samsung Smart Manager on a testing device. I feel its hard to understand without having one. 

Answer (score -1):

The error message is very clear, **10 crashes in 1 week**. I would clearly say that the app is sub standard.

You should start with implementing a Global Exceptional Handler or start using some specialized service such as "Crashlytics" in you App to understand what is going on.

Comment: No, error != crash ... error for smart manager can be for example: keep the screen on, take to much RAM or CPU, etc...

Comment: I would be double sure about the crashes with crashlytics enabled before moving to blame samsung. Also Android Studio proved performance related inspections; run those inspections and remove all the violations if you think that the errors are only highlighting battery drain issues.

Comment: A global exception handler, that's what I tried first  I told you clearly I'm handling all exceptions, there are definitely no unhandled exceptions thrown

Comment: Inspections are a good idea. I had most active already and now avtivated every inspection that could make sence. tried to find relevant stuff and did some minor things like replacing expensive collections with ArrayLists, but nothing really exciting found. Now build, installed and need to wait DAYS  now again if it pops "error" up again or not. Guys, this would drive you also mad, be sure... And note, "error" can be anything and can have nothing to do with battery. As somebody said it can be anything like RAM, CPU, Energy, concurrent threads, verbose logging, unhandled exceptions, ......???

Comment: "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth". As an android developer I have my own set of inspections always set. I would suggest you keep working on the inspection and be patient.